# Is there any way to create hidden directory using cordova File plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to hide directory which contain audio files created by cordova app so that user don't delete files.I create directory using File plugin

```
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; // to get root path of directory
    directoryEntry.getDirectory(Folder_Name, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail); // creating folder in sdcard
```

Is there any way to create hidden directory ?or please give me any other option to prevent user from deleting app generated files...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this. If you want the user to have access to the audio files, you could try the Media plugin and point to a remote url. It would only work while online of course.

Comment: I already using media plugin which is point to remote url but I also added download option so that user also can listen offline

Comment: And as soon as you do, you give up control over the asset and the user can steal it. However, I honestly think this will be a small minority of users who can fetch it. But I'd consider it like any other media online - if a person is motivated, they can get and keep the audio.